# Microsoft Graph: how to get Data from users of an organisation through web app?

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am building a web application that needs to access the tasks from Outlook tasks of some the users of my organisation. I know this functionality is fairly new to Microsoft Graph according to this:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog#outlook-tasks

When I use Graph Explorer I can get all my tasks with this call:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks

But my tasks or the current user's tasks are not what I need. I need to have access to the tasks list of all the users of Outlook task in my organisation regardless of who is currently connected in the app. I know i can use something like this to get tasks from a spcific user:

```
GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/outlook/tasks
```

But i always recevie the follwing response:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
>           "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
>           "innerError": {
>               "request-id": "5831bd5b-8fd1-4f77-b49b-c976ddffab3f",
>               "date": "2017-07-18T15:42:49"
>           }
>       }
>   }

I have grant every administrator's permissions but I still receive the same response. Did I skipped importants steps? If so, what are those steps? Can I test this functionality in Graph Explorer or I must test it in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you can only access Outlook Tasks using delegated permissions (i.e. on behalf of the current user). You can reach outside their own tasks using the `Tasks.Read.Shared` scope but again, this only provide additional access to Outlook Tasks that were shared with the current user.

What you're looking for here would be `Tasks.Read.All` or `Tasks.ReadWrite.All` permissions. These would fall under Application Permissions and require Administrative Consent. At the moment this functionality isn't available, although I'm sure it is being considered. I would certainly recommend posting this suggestion in the [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: If everyone in my organisation would share their outlook tasks folder with me, could I access all of their tasks with this call? https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks

Comment: In theory, sure. If you're looking for a more uniform task model however, you may want to consider Planner instead. It may be more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: I can't even get my own tasks?! How to provide these scopes in the middleware (.NET Core Web API)?

Comment: For anyone looking, this is the [suggestion on User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/20160895-add-permissions-tasks-read-all-or-tasks-readwrite).