# I want to read tasks from Microsoft Graph Beta

Tags: c#, .net, azure, permissions, microsoft-graph-api

I'm reading this article: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/outlookuser_list_tasks

I am trying to retrieve all Tasks, but receive AccessDenied - 403 status code, despite I set Tasks.Read, Tasks.Write, Tasks.ReadWrite in my profile (o365 account).

In the section `Permissions`, what does `Application - Not Supported mean? Am I supposed to add these Tasks. ReadWrite permissions in my code (.NET Core Web API). How?

Comment: Are you able to make less privileged requests, such as fetching the current user's profile info (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me)?

Answer (score 0):

> In the section Permissions, what does `Application - Not Supported mean?

> **Application permissions** are used by apps that run without a signed-in user present; for example, apps that run as background services or daemons.

[List tasks](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/outlookuser_list_tasks) is used to get all the Outlook tasks in the user's mailbox. Detailed documentation about Microsoft Graph permissions, you could follow [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#delegated-permissions-application-permissions-and-effective-permissions).

> Am I supposed to add these Tasks. ReadWrite permissions in my code (.NET Core Web API)

[List tasks](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/outlookuser_list_tasks) requires the least permission **Tasks.Read**. For detailed Tasks permissions, you could follow [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#tasks-permissions).

Moreover, I would recommend you use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to decode your token and check your delegated permissions under the `scp` property. If you still could not solve this issue, please update your question with the details (AD v1.0 or v2.0, code snippet,etc.) about this issue for us to narrow this issue.

Comment: To clarify, Application level permissions not being supported means that You can't read Tasks from all users by using an Application level token?

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45172522/310988) clarifies that you cannot read Tasks with an Application level token. The best you can do is share Task folders with others, and then you can use a User level token with the Tasks.Read.Shared permission.